# How to use sql commands with psql copy in the same file

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a series to sql commands that I'm running, and one of them is a copy of the sql results to a file. I then want to drop the table. Here's an example:

```
psql - d dw -U postgres -f input.sql
```

contents of input.sql ---------

```
CREATE TABLE a_temp AS
SELECT a.*
    FROM a

COPY dw.a_temp to '/opt/data/a/a.csv (delimiter E'\x01');

DROP table a_temp;
```

Is this all possible to do in one file? Right now the script just stops after the CREATE TABLE, and the copy is never run. We're trying to avoid multiple invocation of the PSQL executable.

Comment: What is your version of postgresql? In later versions you can `COPY` directly from a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What is your version of postgresql? In later versions you can COPY directly from a SELECT query. – Igor Romanchenko*

This is the solution I ultimately went with. So the statement looks like

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM a)
TO '/opt/data/a/a.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER E'\x01';
```

No temporary table necessary!

Comment: If you take all the columns anyway why don't you use simple 
COPY a
TO '/opt/data/a/a.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER E'\x01';

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon after CREATE TABLE and missing apostrophe after path.

```
CREATE TABLE a_temp AS
SELECT * FROM a;

COPY dw.a_temp TO '/opt/data/a/a.csv' DELIMITER E'\x01';

DROP table a_temp;
```

Depending on context there can be also problem with schema. If you set SEARCH_PATH to 'dw' it should work, otherwise you probably create table a_temp in public, and try to copy from dw.

Comment: I had to retype everything I posted from the original, so the things you pointed out were typos.

Comment: Like @Igor Romanchenko wrote in his comment you can try: COPY (SELECT * FROM a) TO '/path/to/file' DELIMITER E'\x01'; although CREATE TABLE, COPY, DROP works perfectly for me. You don't get any warnings / errors when you run your script?

Comment: No, no warning/errors at all. It just stopped running. But I really prefer Igor's suggestion anyway, as it eliminates the need for the space taken by the temp table.

Comment: Yeah, but it is still annoying :)